# Elasticsearch Nested Query matching and/or

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

For example, I have data containing the following:

```
{
  author: "test",
  books: [
    {
      name: "first book",
      cost: 50
    },
    {
      name: "second book",
      cost: 100
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search the author which has ALL books with `cost > 40`. How would the query for that look like? The field `books` is mapped as `nested property`.

Answer (score 1):

**For author names with cost of one book greater than 40 (in hits), something as below in query would work**

```
POST http://192.168.0.68:9200/library/Book/_search
{
   "fields": ["author"], 
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "books",
               "filter": {
                  "range": {
                     "books.cost": {
                        "gt": 40
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For all books having cost **greater than 40**, I had to handle the **collection** of nested field manually in client side after getting the response.

Not sure if script applies here to apply filter to all nested objects.

**Reference**

[document not in nested documents elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25527529/432903)

Comment: Yep was using that query as well for ANY books greater than 40, which works well. However, ALL seem to be a harder issue. Client side filter would be my last resort though, if it is not at all possible in elastic search. Thanks!